# ERROR SQL syntax for database named 'not'

Tags: mysql

Named a database `not` and now it won't let it give me permissions or even drop it in command line on Linux.

Comment: Don't name your database with a reserved word, and you will `not` have this problem. :-)

Comment: Had a strange feeling it might be a reserved word! haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not** is a reserved keyword in MYSQL. You need backticks to use that, something like this:-

```
drop database `not`
```

**On a side note:-**

It is generally not a good practice to name your tables and database names with **[reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `not` with backticks. Example

```
drop database `not`
```

Comment: I was able to drop it only when i did so from mysqladmin.